# css3 animation rotation stutter

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a css3 animation, it's a rotation set on an infinite loop, the problem is once it's done a rotation it doesn't smoothly go into the rotation again, there is a stutter of some sort and I can't quite figure out why.

This is the css for it, and you can see it in action here: http://www.klossal.com/sixred/discovery/groundup.html

HTML:

```
<div class="back_rays-container">
     <img class="back-rays" src="images/start-imgs/back-rays.png" />    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-ms-keyframes backRays {
    0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}
@-moz-keyframes backRays {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}
@-webkit-keyframes backRays {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(100deg) }
}
@keyframes backRays {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }    
}

.back_rays-container {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:33;  
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-animation-name: backRays;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 9000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name: backRays;
    -moz-animation-duration: 9000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -ms-animation-name: backRays;
    -ms-animation-duration:9000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.back-rays {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you spot that the webkit animation goes to 100deg instead of 360 ?

Comment: that's it!  If you wanna throw that in the answer I'll accept it